# The attribute name of [ *ngIf ] must be in lowercase

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can you please tell me how to remove below message on `VS code` editor?

```
The attribute name of [ *ngIf ] must be in lowercase.
```

Above message shows on below code

```html
 <div *ngIf="isBornOn">

 </div>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think it has to do with the **vscode-htmlhint** plugin, try disable it.

If that removed the warning you can disable just that rule by setting `attr-lowercase` to false.

Read more about the configuration of this plugin [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkaufman.HTMLHint)

In VSCode you can set the following settings to disable it.:

```
"htmlhint.options": {
  "attr-lowercase": false
}
```

If don't want lose warning when use attributes that don't follow lower case rule. Instead of, you can define an [attribute white list](https://github.com/thedaviddias/HTMLHint/wiki/Attr-lowercase):

```
"htmlhint.options": {
    "attr-lowercase": [
      "*ngIf",
      "ngIf",
      "*ngFor",
      "ngFor",
      "ngSwitch",
      "ngModel"
    ],
    "doctype-first": false
  },
```

Also can add `doctype-first` to avoid that message on every component.

Answer (score 18):

Anyone looking to solve this from another IDE such as Eclipse or Codemix, simply create a file called `.htmlhintrc` place this in `/<angular-project>/src/.htmlhintrc`
and change the values as you see fit, mine are:

```
{
    "tagname-lowercase": false,
    "attr-lowercase": false,
    "attr-value-double-quotes": true,
    "doctype-first": false,
    "tag-pair": true,
    "spec-char-escape": true,
    "id-unique": true,
    "src-not-empty": true,
    "attr-no-duplication": true,
    "title-require": true
}
```

Re-open the tab if not automatically resolved or then restart the IDE.

Comment: This is a better answer, since I can now just commit this file to git and all devs will benefit from standard behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: Solved from VS Code as well. No restart or reopen required.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

Under VS Code - Extensions (left sidebar - box-shaped icon) - Disable this plugin or uninstall if required.

Then Reboot