# VScode angular material syntax

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-material

is there any way to add angular-material syntax to visual studio code? 
I always get errors like

`The attribute name of [ matColumnDef ] must be in lowercase.`

`The attribute name of [ matColumnDef ] must be in lowercase.` etc...

I try to find extension but nothing help. 
Here is preview
[image]

Comment: might it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684599/the-attribute-name-of-ngif-must-be-in-lowercase

Comment: @SarjeraoGhadage thnx. I already saw this and try, but still no help. Because In this case I need to know all material TAGS and put it in attr-lowercase, but there is too many of them.

Comment: do you use  vscode-htmlhint plugin??

Comment: Yes i use htmlhint plugin